# Implementation of a queue for digicode-like system

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, reinventing-the-wheel, queue

**What it is about**

I created an application where you need to push invisible buttons in a certain order to unlock the *advanced* mode. To handle this, I wanted to use a queue ([FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics))) of my own, adapted to my problem.

Every time I click a button, its ID is added to the queue with `addItem`, and the password gets checked with `checkCorrect`. It is meant to work similarly to digicode doors. The `size` attribute determines how many values the queue can remember, hence the maximum length of the password.

**What I'd like to know**

Do you think this is a good code? In which ways can it be improved? Are there other ways (with smaller / more elegant code) to implement this?

**The code**

```
class MyQueue():
    def __init__(self, size, default_value=None):
        self.size = size
        self.content = [default_value]*size
        self.end = self.size-1
    def addItem(self, value):
        self.end = (self.end+1) % self.size
        self.content[self.end] = value
    def printQueue(self):
        print 'end='+str(self.end)+' - '+str(self.content)
    def checkCorrect(self, password):
        pw = list(reversed(password))
        i = 0
        j = self.end
        if len(pw) > self.size:
            return False
        while True:
            if pw[i] <> self.content[j]:
                return False
            else:
                i += 1
                j = (j-1) % self.size
                if i == len(pw):
                    return True

if __name__=='__main__':
    q = MyQueue(size=4, default_value=0)
    q.addItem(1)
    q.addItem(8)
    q.addItem(8)
    q.addItem(5)
    q.addItem(7)
    q.addItem(3)
    print q.checkCorrect([5, 7, 3])
    print q.checkCorrect([2, 7, 3])
```

Comment: What is `defaultValue` ? You meant `default_value` I guess? More, do NOT use `<>` operator. It's kind of unusual and unsupported in Python 3.5 (even if you're using python 2.7). Use `!=` instead. You're code as it is, it's off-topic. Please edit it.

Comment: I edited the variable name, thanks for noticing it. It didn't know for `<>` and `!=`, do you want to make it an answer ?
Besides, please how can I make this less off-topic ? I don't understand how it is off-topic in the first place...

Comment: Why are you implementing a queue yourself? https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html

Comment: Well I found this interesting, and I wanted some object that I fully understand, and adapted to my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## object

Since it is Python 2, you most likely want to use [new-style classes](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) instead of old ones. Meaning that `MyQueue` must explicitly inherit from object:

```
class MyQueue(object):
    ...
```

## `__iter__`

Since you are creating a container, you should provide an easy way to iterate over its content. That easy way is done by [implementing `__iter__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019971/how-to-implement-iter-self-for-a-container-object-python) which let you use:

```
container = MyQueue()
...  # Do stuff to populate container
for element in container:
    print(element)
```

A first approach could be:

```
class MyQueue(object):
    ...
    def __iter__(self):
        size = self.size  # cache value in local scope for faster access
        for i in xrange(self.end, self.end + size):
            yield self.content[i % size]
```

This helps you simplify `checkCorrect`:

```
    def checkCorrect(self, password):
        if len(password) != self.size:
            return False
        return all(val == passwd for val, passwd in zip(self, reversed(password)))
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Some [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidance:

`class MyQueue():` here, you can remove the redundant parentheses as you're not passing any parameter to it. So you will have `class MyQueue`.

When inside of a class, it's recommended to have one <kbd>space</kbd> between your methods:

```
def addItem:
    ....

def printQueue:
    ....
```

It's also specified in PEP8 the following (methods naming):

> Use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by
>   underscores as necessary to improve readability.

That said, `addItem` would become `add_item`.

#### More

Don't use `<>` operator. It's not usual. I strongly recommend you using `!=` operator (which is the common way of doing this) when you're trying to say `not equal`. Later on, you might want to use this with a more recent Python version (say Python 3.5). This way, you won't have any issues.

Related to portability, you might also want to add parentheses when using `print()`. It's not necessary since you're using Python 2.7, but it might help you in the future.

Classes and methods inside them usually have [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#id15). To quote the documentation:

> A docstring is a string literal that occurs as the first statement in
>   a module, function, class, or method definition. Such a docstring
>   becomes the **doc** special attribute of that object.
>
> All modules should normally have docstrings, and all functions and
>   classes exported by a module should also have docstrings.

That said:

```
class MyQueue:
    """Some text to describe what you're class does"""
    ....

    def add_item(self, value):
        """ what this method does """
        ...
```

In a perfect world, which obviously we're not living in, I would've expect to see some `push` / `pop` methods or `queue` / `dequeue` ones since we're talking about a queue implementation and it's way of handling things (FIFO). Perhaps `add_item` might be `push_item`.

*More to come*